Databricks Workflow Task doesn't fail when making a typo in dbt commands
I'm trying to create a Databricks Workflow with 3 dbt tasks: Running Bronze, Silver and Gold models. To try out the "repair run" function, I made a typo on purpose in one of dbt commands. However, I noticed that when dbt can't find any models to run, it doesn't raise an error. Instead Databricks continues with the next task.
Is there any smart workaround, or I just shouldn't make typos in dbt commands?
Dbt command with typo in databricks workflow:
dbt run --models silvera
Log:
+ dbt run --models silvera

12:19:36  Running with dbt=1.8.4
12:19:38  Registered adapter: databricks=1.8.4
12:19:38  Unable to do partial parsing because saved manifest not found. Starting full parse.
12:19:40  Found 2 models, 1 source, 588 macros
12:19:40  The selection criterion 'silvera' does not match any enabled nodes
12:19:40  
12:19:40  Nothing to do. Try checking your model configs and model specification args

Expected behavior: Databricks raising an error that the task was unsuccessful.
